# c# - trying to play a video in a picturebox

Tags: c#, picturebox

I want to play a small video in a `PictureBox`. I have a folder on my desktop containing 151 frames with a .png extension. This is what I have already tried:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\Users\\" + Environment.UserName + "\\Desktop\\fireplace");

foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
{
    pictureBox1.Image = file;
}
```

This doesn't work because there's an error that says:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `System.IO.FileInfo` to `System.Drawing.Image`

I don't know how to make `FileInfo` to an `Image`.
(btw. the fireplace folder in the code is the folder that contains the frames.)

Comment: Use [Image.FromFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromfile(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Also you can add a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` after which images will switch.

Comment: John Wu, can you show example code? Im such a noob i dont know how to use it >_<

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to load all of the images into one `List<Bitmap>` and then use `Timer` to change the pictures inside `PictureBox` :

```
List<Bitmap> _images = new List<Bitmap>();
int _currentImageIndex = 0;

int CurrentImageIndex
{
    get { return _currentImageIndex; }
    set {
        _currentImageIndex = value;
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker( () => { _pictureBox.Image = _images[_currentImageIndex]; } );
        }
        else 
        {
            _pictureBox.Image = _images[_currentImageIndex];
        }
    }
}

Bitmap LoadImage(Stream stream)
{
    return new Bitmap(stream, false);
}

public void LoadImages(DirectoryInfo dInfo)
{
    foreach(FileInfo fInfo in dInfo.GetFiles())
    {
        if(InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker( () => { _images.Add(LoadImage (fInfo.Open(FileMode.Open))); });
        }
        else
        {
            _images.Add(LoadImage (fInfo.Open()));
        }
    }
}

void WhenTimerTicks(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(CurrentImageIndex < _images.Count)
        CurrentImageIndex++;
}
```

Now all you have to do is to read the files and after that set up your timer :

```
LoadImages(new DirectoryInfo("c:\\Users\\" + Environment.UserName + "\\Desktop\\fireplace"));

Timer t = new Timer();
t.Interval = 1000 / 25; // 25 FPS
t.Tick += WhenTimerTicks;
t.Start();
```

Comment: You beat me by 5 mins.

Comment: @BladeMight You can always put your suggestion if it differs and maybe Someone else will find it more helpfull then mine :)

Comment: @m.rogalski Nah, its almost same :]

Comment: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.IO.FileStream' to 'System.Drawing.Bitmap'

Comment: @diPokiI Can you show what you've done? It works on my end.

Comment: @diPokil Now should work. Forgot about calling `LoadImage` method.

Answer (score 0):

m.rogalski:

```
List<Bitmap> _images = new List<Bitmap>();
    int _currentImageIndex = 0;

    int CurrentImageIndex
    {
        get { return _currentImageIndex; }
        set
        {
            _currentImageIndex = value;
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { pictureBox1.Image = _images[_currentImageIndex]; });
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = _images[_currentImageIndex];
            }
        }
    }

    Bitmap LoadImage(Stream stream)
    {
        return new Bitmap(stream, false);
    }

    public void LoadImages(DirectoryInfo dInfo)
    {
        foreach (FileInfo fInfo in dInfo.GetFiles())
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { _images.Add(fInfo.Open(FileMode.Open)); })); //Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.IO.FileStream' to 'System.Drawing.Bitmap'
            }
            else
            {
                _images.Add(fInfo.Open(FileMode.Open)); //Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.IO.FileStream' to 'System.Drawing.Bitmap'
            }
        }
    }

    void WhenTimerTicks(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CurrentImageIndex < _images.Count)
            CurrentImageIndex++;
    }
```